# How do I loop a dice game in c#?

Tags: c#, loops

I have to make a dice game in which the player plays with a shopkeeper, this is just a part of a bigger program in which the player has to interact with the shopkeeper. The player has a certain amount of gold, and in every turn the player can win 1.1 gold, lose 1 or it can be draw. The player has the choice to play or not. And I want to loop it as many as times as the player wants to play it again and has at least 1 gold, and when he decides not to play anymore then the loop should stop. I tried to search for tutorials, but didn't find anything particularly helpful.

```
Console.WriteLine("Do you want to play a game of dices with me to win some gold?");
Console.WriteLine("You can lose 1 gold or you can win 1.1 gold.");
Console.WriteLine("Wanna play? y or n");
var diceAnswer = Console.ReadLine();

switch (diceAnswer)
{
    case "y":
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int playerRoll = rnd.Next(1, 7);
        Console.WriteLine("You rolled {0}", playerRoll);
        int shopRoll = rnd.Next(1, 7);
        Console.WriteLine("I rolled {0}", shopRoll);
        if (playerRoll > shopRoll)
        {
            goldLeft += 1.1;
            Console.WriteLine("You won 1.1 gold, therefore you now have " + goldLeft + " gold");
        }
        else if (playerRoll < shopRoll)
        {
            goldLeft--;
            Console.WriteLine("You lost 1 gold, therefore you now have " + goldLeft + " gold");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("That is a draw. Seems that we are both lucky");
        }
        break;

    case "n":
        Console.WriteLine("That is a safe choice.");
        break;

    default :
        Console.WriteLine("Since that is not a good answer, I will not play with you");
        break;
}
```

Comment: did you try using While loop??

Comment: [Loops documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f0e10e56(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: for (var diceAnswer = Console.ReadLine(); diceAnswer != n;)

Comment: the odds should always be in favor of the house as well

Comment: You are re-seeding the PRNG every time the game starts which you shouldn't really do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that (*while loop* with `break`s):

```
// do not re-create Random
private static Random rnd = new Random();
...

Console.WriteLine("Do you want to play a game of dices with me to win some gold?");
Console.WriteLine("You can lose 1 gold or you can win 1.1 gold.");

while (goldLeft >= 1.0) { // you must have enough gold if you want to play 
  Console.WriteLine("Wanna play? y or n");

  string answer = Console.ReadLine();

  if (answer.Equals("n")) {
    Console.WriteLine("That is a safe choice.");
    break;
  }
  else if (!answer.Equals("y")) {
    Console.WriteLine("Since that is not a good answer, I will not play with you");
    break;
  }

  // Case "y" here
  int playerRoll = rnd.Next(1, 7);
  int shopRoll = rnd.Next(1, 7);  

  if (playerRoll > shopRoll) {
    goldLeft += 1.1;
    Console.WriteLine("You won 1.1 gold, therefore you now have " + goldLeft + " gold");
  }
  else if (playerRoll < shopRoll) {
    goldLeft -= 1.0;
    Console.WriteLine("You lost 1 gold, therefore you now have " + goldLeft + " gold");
  }
  else {
    Console.WriteLine("That is a draw. Seems that we are both lucky");
  }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is so cool, I was trying to solve for two days. Thank you for enlightening me :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use a do-while loop to always run the first time, but break out at the end if the player decides not to continue like this:

```
bool keepPlaying = true;

do {

    Console.WriteLine("Do you want to play a game of dices with me to win some gold?");
    Console.WriteLine("You can lose 1 gold or you can win 1.1 gold.");
    Console.WriteLine("Wanna play? y or n");
    var diceAnswer = Console.ReadLine();

    switch (diceAnswer)
    {
        case "y":
            keepPlaying = true;
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int playerRoll = rnd.Next(1, 7);
            Console.WriteLine("You rolled {0}", playerRoll);
            int shopRoll = rnd.Next(1, 7);
            Console.WriteLine("I rolled {0}", shopRoll);
            if (playerRoll > shopRoll)
            {
                goldLeft += 1.1;
                Console.WriteLine("You won 1.1 gold, therefore you now have " + goldLeft + " gold");
            }
            else if (playerRoll < shopRoll)
            {
                goldLeft--;
                Console.WriteLine("You lost 1 gold, therefore you now have " + goldLeft + " gold");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("That is a draw. Seems that we are both lucky");
            }
            break;

        case "n":
            keepPlaying = false;
            Console.WriteLine("That is a safe choice.");
            break;

        default :
            keepPlaying = false;
            Console.WriteLine("Since that is not a good answer, I will not play with you");
            break;
    }

} while (keepPlaying);
```

You can learn more about do-while loops [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/do) but in principle, the contents of the do block execute at least once, and are re-executing while the conditional statement at the end in the while statement evaluate to true.